# How to make python code simpler

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have following python code. Can i optimise it to one line:

```
url = request.session.get('my_value', '/')
    if url == '/None/':
        url = '/'
```

Any help will be appericiated

Comment: url = '/' if url == '/None/': else url = request.session.get ('my_value', '/')
Try this

Answer (score 2):

```
url = re.sub("^/None/$","/",request.session.get('my_value', '/'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work:

```
url = [request.session.get('my_value', '/'), '/']['/None/' in request.session.get('my_value', '/')]
```

But honestly, it makes the code much more horrible to read...

Answer (score -2):

```
url = '/' if url == '/None/': else url = request.session.get ('my_value', '/')
```